# Javascript: Change label background color on checkbox

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox, background-color

I am trying to change the background color of a label in each checkbox in a form based on the checked/unchecked state of the checkbox.So far I got it to change initially, but it won't change back when I uncheck:

http://jsfiddle.net/7wnCL/4/

javascript:

```
function statecheck(layer) {
var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer);
 if(myLayer.checked = true){
 myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#bff0a1";
 } else {
 myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
 };
}
```

html:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<label title="Alabama" id="Alabama"><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" onchange="statecheck('Alabama')" />AL</label>
<label title="Alaska" id="Alaska"><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" onchange="statecheck('Alaska')" />AK</label>
<label title="American Samoa" id="AmericanSamoa"><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" onchange="statecheck('AmericanSamoa')" />AS</label>
</form>
```

css:

```
label {
margin:0px 2px 4px 2px; 
padding: 1px;
background-color: #eee;
display: block;
width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: myLayer.checked === true

Comment: While there are other syntactical errors, it will not work mostly because you're checking if your label is checked, not the input.

Comment: I just realized that (=== rather than =), but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Josh is there a way to check if the child (the checkbox) is checked?

Comment: @user2219915 Yep! Look at bwoebi's answer with a working fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7wnCL/20/

```
myLayer.checked = true
```

is an assignment, not a condition.

```
if (myLayer.checked = true)
```

is every time evaluated as

```
if (true)
```

And the else part will never be executed. So change it to:

```
if (myLayer.checked === true)
```

Also, you should check for the input, and not for the layer, which doesn't have any checked property:

```
if (myLayer.childNodes[0].checked === true)
```

Comment: And the fact `myLayer` refers to the label, and not the input. There is no checked property of label.

Answer (score 1):

the non-jQuery route. pass a second param to your statecheck function.

```
 <label title="American Samoa" id="AmericanSamoa"><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" onchange="statecheck(this,'AmericanSamoa')" />AS</label>
```

and the javascript

```
 function statecheck(chk, layer) {
var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer);
//myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#bff0a1";
if(chk.checked === true){
    myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#bff0a1";
    } else {
    myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7wnCL/4/

Answer (score 1):

My solution based on your helpful input:

```
function statecheck(layer) {
var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer);
//myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#bff0a1";
if(myLayer.childNodes[0].checked === true){
    myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#bff0a1";
    } else {
    myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
};

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7wnCL/29/

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of mistakes, in your script.

- You are passing lable id and checking for labelId.checked which does
  not exist
- You are using = in if condition which should be ==

This is how you JS method should look like

```
function statecheck(layer, checkbox) {
    var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer);
    //myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#bff0a1";
    if(checkbox.checked == true){
        myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#bff0a1";
        } else {
        myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
    };

}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" onchange="statecheck('Alabama', this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an equals in the if statement..
Is that a typo error or is the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your are not setting the color on the label but on the checkbox.
jQuery makes it easy for you to select / traverse DOM elements (and also helps clean-up a lot of unnecessary IDs), see this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/7wnCL/17/

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){   
        $(this).parent().css('backgroundColor', '#bff0a1');
    }else{
        $(this).parent().css('backgroundColor', '#eee');        
    }
});
```

Comment: You generally shouldn't use jQuery when a question isn't tagged with it and no jQuery is used in the code.

Comment: @bwoebi : Ok but you see, you didn't even see the mistake yourself at first. You only replied about the assignment problem to begin with. It can be beneficial to OP to learn about tools that can make their code easier to read and maintain next time.

Comment: I'm only saying this because some people already said this to me; principally I have no problem with it ;-)

Comment: Yup, thanks, trying to avoid jQuery for this. It would make life easy but I can't use it for this particular project.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the '==' typo mentioned by others, you are also checking whether the label is checked rather than the input. Try:

```
function statecheck(layer) {
    var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer),
        input = myLayer.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    //myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#bff0a1";
    if(input.checked == true){
        myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#bff0a1";
        } else {
        myLayer.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
    };
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7wnCL/26/