# form sum class change on if not firing right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use javascript in a form for validation and am having an issue with the if statement not firing properly, it keeps returning as all true and i have tried changing values but it keeps adding the class with any keyup fire that i self induce and am confused as to why this is happening.

```
$(".components").delegate('.percValue','keyup',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var sum = 0;
        $('.percValue').each(function() {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $(".totalPerc").val(sum.toFixed(2));
        if (sum = 100.00){
            $('.saveing').addClass('auth');
        } else {
            $('.saveing').removeClass('auth');
        }
    });
```

Any ideas or help would be great in order to make this work!

Comment: missing a "=" on the if-statement. should be if(sum == 100.00).

Comment: If the missing `=` is the problem, there's a good explanation on this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16679435/710446

Comment: It's always better to provide with example data (the HTML in this case). Consider using jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thank you very much ninja i was looking at it and somehow forgot that bit, sometimes it pays to just step back and re look at it apsillers i didnt realize there was a duplicate i had searched for a bit looking for whey it didnt want to work for a bit.