# CSS Highlight selected text with search suggestion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm just a beginner in css and html. I would like to create a webpage that has a list of names and I should be able to **select name/names from the list** (can be more than one). I would like to know if there is a way for the background of the specific text to be highlighted instead of a box being checked on the side.

I would also like a **search suggestion** that can navigate throughout the list.

I have this piece of code that search for a specific label

```
function Search() {
    var input, filter, form, label, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("Input");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    form = document.getElementById("Input");
    label = ul.getElementsByTagName("label");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = label[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            label[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            label[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

Along with this piece of code that displays the list

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_list[]\" value=\"{$row['UserIndex']} class=\"studentUL\"\"><label><a>{$row['LName']}, {$row['FName']}, {$row['Year']}</a></label>";
```

But when I search, it displays  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQyCn.png)
. Without any searches, it displays [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCNMj.png)

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a similar question at [Javascript: Change label background color on checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679366/javascript-change-label-background-color-on-checkbox) that answers the part of your question except for search